# class of typedefs

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have seen the following piece of code at work

```
typedef int         real_type;
typedef vector<int> vector_type;


template <class ASD> class program_class
{
  public:
    typename ASD::vector_type member_func();
};


template <typename ASD> typename ASD::real_type program_class<ASD>::member_func()
{
    typedef typename ASD::real_type      R;
    typedef typename ASD::vector_type    V;

    return 123;
}
```

---

Conceptually, I don't understand how the return-type can be stated like this: `typename ASD::real_type`. In principle this requires that the type we instantiate `ASD` with is a class of typedefs, right?

Can I see an example of how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `vector_type` is in the global namespace. If you use the scope operator `::` the scope is changed to that left of the scope operator, in the case of the templates the scope is `ASD` and no longer the global scope.

That means, as you noticed, that the `ASD` class (whatever that is) must have its own `vector_type` and `real_type` defined inside it, or the compiler will give you an error.

---

Example:

```
typedef int real_type;  // The global type alias
...

struct Foo
{
    typedef long real_type;  // The local type alias
    ...
};

program_class<Foo> my_program_object;
```

Now inside the `program_class` the `real_type` will be `Foo::real_type` and not the global `::real_type`.

And as you can see in my example, you can use different base types, as the two type aliases are completely separate from each other.

Comment: Then I move those two lines inside the class-decleration. Then how will it look if I make an object of class `ASD`?

Comment: @BillyJean Added some simple example

Comment: Thanks. The example I showed in the OP combined with your solution, is that a "clever" construction? I mean, can you comment on the "professionalism" of it?

Comment: @BillyJean Many of the standard C++ classes uses type aliases defined in classes that way, so I would say it's very "professional". :

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Processing the declaration with such a return type causes instantiation of whatever, if any, class template `ASD` refers to.

If a member declaration in `ASD` has an error, then the compiler will complain that nested instantiation of `ASD` failed while instantiating `program_class< ASD >`.